# Comma-delimited values not working in an in statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

The following query works :

```
Declare @Product varchar(max) = '0022'

select * 
from Prod 
where ProdId in (@Product)
```

The following also works :

```
select * 
from Prod 
where ProdId in (0022,0033)
```

But the below doesn't work :

```
Declare @Product varchar(max) = '0022,0033'

select *  
from Prod 
where ProdId in (@Product)
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: That isn't how parameters work. They hold a scalar value and can't be used like this. You have a few options. You can pass in a table valued parameter, you can split your string, or you can use dynamic sql.

Comment: The `IN` operator expects a **list of something** - like a list of integers - but what you're providing it in the last sample is a **single string** - not a list of anything..... you'd have to first **split up** that string into a list (table variable) of integer values, and *then* use those values in your `IN` operator....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your codes are all 4 digits you could use **CHARINDEX** to check for the code in the string.

```
SELECT *  
FROM Prod 
WHERE CHARINDEX(ProdId, @Product) > 0
```

If the codes can be of different lengths, add a comma before and after @Product so that you wont get **12345** when searching for **123**.

```
SET @Product = ',' + @Product + ',' 

SELECT *  
FROM Prod 
WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + ProdId + ',' , @Product) > 0
```

The more correct way to do it would be to create a temp table and insert the values:

```
SELECT CAST('0022' AS VARCHAR(20)) AS CODE
UNION 
SELECT CAST('0033' AS VARCHAR(20)) AS CODE
INTO #TEMP_CODES

SELECT * 
FROM Prod 
WHERE ProdId IN (SELECT CODE FROM #TEMP_CODES)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I like the temp table approach but how can I extract the comma delimited values into a temp table ?

Comment: Where are you getting your values from now? It looks like you have them hard coded in your query.

Comment: oh yes .. I need to make this a stored procedure that takes comma delimited characters as an input

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this directly but there is a work around. Michelle Ufford has an excellent article in [SQLFool](http://sqlfool.com//?s=dba_parseString_udf) on a function named "dba_parseString_udf" that will do what you need.

Oddly, you can do this (e.g. pass a comma delimited string to an IN clause) in a SQL statement that is embedded in SSRS when using a multi-select list.